# Update menuItem icon from custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, menuitem

I have a Gridview list inside a fragment. I am using custom adapter and it's xml has imageview that is clickable (For Favourite).

Now I have actionbar using the usual menu.xml to show icons on the actionbar. I have custom XML to show icon with text counter.

So In menu.xml I am calling the following: Where act_fav is the xml that has the imageview and textview.

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_fav"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/act_fav"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_starnofill"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_fav"/>
```

act_fav - has imageView and textView for showing image a textabove it.

Now, whenever I click on favourite icon how do I update the menuItem icon and add value to textView in actionbar from my CustomAdapter?

I am able to do inside the fragment by calling:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) 
{   
    RelativeLayout favLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.action_fav).getActionView();
    favLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    favTV = (TextView) favLayout.findViewById(R.id.fav_number);
    favTV.setText("12");

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}
```

But how do I call the same from Custom Adapter?

Let me know!

Comment: hi do you want to change the action bar icon or menu icon?. I mean both action bar icon and menu options are different. what do you want ?

Comment: @BhavdipPathar - I want to change fill.png to filled.png and then I have xml that has a counter that has to be added to it.

Comment: For change the fill.png to filled.png it could possible using menu object. You can see the posted answer below. I could not get you the counter you talking about :)

Comment: @BhavdipPathar - I have an custom xml only for action_fav and calling that in menu.xml like this: <item
        android:id="@+id/action_fav"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/favourite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_stillnofill"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/action_fav"/>

Comment: So Where is the fill.png place in layout, where you want to change it dynamically. I think it is inside the layout favourite !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update the menu item from on click of custom adapter you could create the global menu object for access it in entire activity/ fragment. we suppose to think that why we should not use findViewById(R.id) for access the menu item. You can not use findViewById for menu item. In short you can follow the below steps.

1. Create the Menu object.

   Private Menu mMenu;
2. In your onCreateOptionsMenu()

   this.menu = menu;
3. In your Custom adapter favourite button click event.

   menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

For example :

```
package test.actionbariconupdate;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class ActionBarIconUpdate extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_action_bar_icon_update2);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private Menu mMenu;
        private Button buttonclick;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_action_bar_icon_update, menu);
            this.mMenu = menu;
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_action_bar_icon_update, container, false);
            buttonclick = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonclick);
            buttonclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(mMenu != null){
                        ImageView imageView  = (ImageView) mMenu.getItem(0).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.menu_icon);
                        imageView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
                    }
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

**menu_action_bar_icon_update.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/action_menu"/>
</menu>
```

**@layout/action_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I run this code I could able to change the icon dynamically. I hope will help you sure.

Comment: I tried your logic and but the Mainactivity is not getting called. I can't see the log. 

I have MainActivity with navigation drawer which has the menu etc. I have Fragment from which I have the customAdapter called. Do I need to call CreateOption inside Fragment or MainActivity is fine.

Comment: Just try override the onCreateOptionsMenu(..) inside your fragment. you can also do it from activity as well. if your current fragment is loaded inside in the  same activity.

Comment: if you want to do it from activity I think you need to make callback to your main activity where you can put your logic for menu update and call your activity function from your fragment's custom adapter. otherwise put the above logic inside your fragment

Comment: @TheDevMan What i did I update the action bar menu item inside the fragment using click event of the fragment button

Comment: Let me know if you really looking something like that ! or do you want to use android:action-layout="" for update the icon dynamically.

Comment: Actually I am looking for a way to update my action-layout icon from CustomAdapter.

Comment: @TheDevMan Please see the code I have updated it. It is used actionLayout

Comment: Wow. Thanks I will check and get back!

Answer (score 1):

Try to Use this

Write this inside your activity

```
    public static boolean isChangeMenu = false;
    public static Menu menu;

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if (isChangeMenu) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.mnu).setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon1);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.mnu).setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon2);
    }

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    this.menu = menu;

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}
```

and use this inside your adapter

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            YourActivityName.isChangeMenu = true;

            if (mContext instanceof YourActivityName) {
                ((YourActivityName) mContext).onPrepareOptionsMenu(YourActivityName.menu);
            }

        }
```

Comment: If I remove instanceof I get NPE in  ((YourActivityName) mContext).onPrepareOptionsMenu(YourActivityName.menu);

Comment: I have Upload a simple demo to change the icon. Download from [link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/m4obrtvj4yb9o5b/ActionBarDemo.zip)